# Foundation (ZURB) and Foundation.Utils

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm new to Foundation and trying to figure out why I can't call any of the Foundation.utils functions within my document. If I type Foundation.utils.random_str(6) into the javascript console I get the desired result, I have this code before body closes any suggestions?

```
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).foundation();
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    alert(Foundation.utils.random_str(6));
    //alert('ready');
});
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you put `$(document).foundation();` inside `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: @Niloct still nothing happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the [Javascript Utilities](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript-utilities.html) documentation for Foundation 5.0.3 and it specifically states:

> As long as foundation.js has been loaded into the page, you can
>   access any of the Foundation utilities by calling
>   Foundation.utils.{function_name}.

I also couldn't get it work so I dug into foundation.min.js and found the `random_str` function, but there is not a reference to `utils` anywhere in the file.

I then tried just `alert(Foundation.random_str(6));` after my `$(document).foundation();` and got it to work. Here is the smallest codepen I have ever made http://cdpn.io/yfpmb to demonstrate it.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Good work Adam. So I guess all utils are methods of the Foundation class and not .utils.

Comment: That's what I am assuming Woods.

Comment: Can't get Foundation.debounce / Foundation.utils.debounce or throttle to work. But the functions are in Foundation.min.js

Comment: From what I have read it looks like depending on what your doing they recommend using the Foundation.inherit method. I suggest asking another question with a jsfiddle or codepen explaining exactly what you are wanting to accomplish. Also include the Foundation version you are working with, I see they are on 5.1.1 now. That way you also get more eyes on the question/issue as well.

Comment: Works with latest update using Foundation.utils! Bugged release I guess.